# C++ Regex Alpha without Equal sign

Tags: c++, regex

im new to Regex and C++.
My problem is, that '=' is matching when I search for [a-zA-Z]. But this is only a-z without '='?

Can anyone help me please?

```
 string string1 = "s=s;";
    enum states state = s1;

    regex statement("[a-zA-Z]+[=][a-zA-Z0-9]+[;]");
    regex rg_left_letter("[a-zA-Z]");
    regex rg_equal("[=]");
    regex rg_right_letter("[a-zA-Z0-9]");
    regex rg_semicolon("[;]");

    for (const auto &s : string1) {
        cout << "Current Value: " << s << endl;
        // step(&state, s);
        if (regex_search(&s, rg_left_letter)) {
            cout << "matching: " << s << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "not matching: " << s << endl;
        }

        // cout << "Step Executed with sate: " << state << endl;
    }
```

This outputs:

```
Current Value: s
matching: s
Current Value: =
matching: =
Current Value: s
matching: s
Current Value: ;
not matching: ;
```

Comment: Why are you passing the address of the string to `regex_search()`, not the string itself? It expects a reference to an `std::string` or ` char*`. Passing a *pointer* to an `std::string` probably invokes some odd conversion that causes strange results.

Comment: I'm further planning to pass that in to several functions for parsing an INI-file with FSA-Patterns.

Comment: What would be the correct Regex for `s` or `S`without `=`??

Comment: What else you're planning to do with this string is completely irrelevant. Again: why are you passing a weird thing to **this** specific stdlib function? What did you expect that to do? What happens if you just pass `s`, not `&s`?

Comment: okay thanks, and how can i loop over my string without using pointers?

like an `foreach(xx as xx)`?

Comment: `error: no matching function for call to 'regex_match'
        if (regex_match(s, rg_left_letter)) {
            ^~~~~~~~~~~`.....

Comment: I was thinking wrongly. For what you're doing, I guess you could use `std::string.substring()` to get a single char, and pass that. But I don't know if that's the right design anyway.

Comment: @underscore_d How would you implement the loop with substring?

`for (int i = 0; i < string1.size(); i++) ` and then use `string1[i]` would be the same, right?

Comment: Well, no, because `operator[]` returns a `char [const] &`, but `regex_match()` wants a `char const*` (which is wrong here for the reasons mentioned) or an `std::string const&`. To do it using `.substring()`, of course just use `.substring(i, 1)`. However, again, I'm not saying this is necessarily what you *should* do, just that it's *how* to do it.

Comment: @underscore_d I solved it!! Thanks to you and @Jodocus !

But in C++ the correct syntax is `string1.substr(i,1);`

Comment: I know what the correct syntax is. I just didn't bother including the object name as I can be a lazy typist and figured you'd realise that was required. Good to hear!

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```
regex_search(&s, rg_left_letter)
```

you basically search the C-String `&s` for a match character-wise, beginning at the character s. Therefore, your loop will search for a match in the remaining sub-strings

```
s=s;
=s;
s;
;
```

Which will always succeed, except in the last case, as there is always one character in the entire string that fits your regex. Note however that this assumes that `std::string` has some 0-termination added, which is, as far as I can tell, not guaranteed if you do not explicitely use the `c_str()` method, making your code UB.
What you really want to use is the function `regex_match`, together with your original regex just as simple as:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    std::regex statement("[a-zA-Z]+[=][a-zA-Z0-9]+[;]");
    if(std::regex_match("s=s;", statement)) { std::cout << "Hooray!\n"; }
}
```

Comment: thanks! I tried it, but `regex_match` is only for the entire string right? in my case I just have one character of my string..

This also fails, with `regex_match(&s, rg_left_letter);`

Comment: Some more exposition would be good. By my understanding, `s` is a reference to a single `char` in the `std::string`'s buffer, and `&s` produces a pointer to that `char`, which then gets intepreted as a pointer to a substring in the original string, resulting in the remainder being searched too.

Comment: okay, I have my string `config=abc`. I have a loop over that entire string.
Thus, I have in my first iteration the `c`, in the next the `o` and so on...

And I want for each single string an regex search / match

Comment: @Markus No, you don't have to loop at all. Let the regex do the work. See also my modified answer.

Comment: @Jodocus thanks at all. But I think this will not solve my problem...

Assume that you don't know that the entire string matches to the statement & you will loop over each character in your string to determine in which regular expression it is. like in my output example `string: c / matches`...

Can follow my minds?

Comment: @Markus No, it is entirely unclear to me what you want to accomplish. If you just want to check if a certain string matches a certain regular expression, you may do as I suggested. No loops, no splitted regular expressions.

Comment: @Jodocus mhh.. okay I wan't to parse the entire string which is "string1=string2". Now I wan't to loop over each single item and do something with it, like an regex check and more... I don't know how to explain it exactlier...

Comment: @Markus If you want to extract data from the string, you must use a `std::smatch` and change the regex to something like `([a-zA-Z]+)[=]([a-zA-Z0-9]+)[;]`. Then, you just loop over the `smatch` object. But if you cannot articulate your problem properly, nobody is able to help you properly, either. Your solution looks suspicious and not like what you really want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
 int main(void) {
        string string1 = "s=s;";
        enum states state = s1;

        regex statement("[a-zA-Z]+[=][a-zA-Z0-9]+[;]");
        regex rg_left_letter("[a-zA-Z]");
        regex rg_equal("[=]");
        regex rg_right_letter("[a-zA-Z0-9]");
        regex rg_semicolon("[;]");

        //for (const auto &s : string1) {

        for (int i = 0; i < string1.size(); i++) {
            cout << "Current Value: " << string1[i] << endl;
            // step(&state, s);
            if (regex_match(string1.substr(i, 1), rg_left_letter)) {
                cout << "matching: " << string1[i] << endl;
            } else {
                cout << "not matching: " << string1[i] << endl;
            }

            // cout << "Step Executed with sate: " << state << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You should index using `std::string::size_type`, not `int` (and same for any other `Container::size_type`). Sure, this code will work unless you start having > 2-million-character long strings or whatever, but it's better to use code with the correct semantics. Also, the `void` parameter list is not needed.

Comment: This means that I need to rewrite `for (size_type = 0;...)` .. I don't know how to work with size_types..

And thanks for the advice with the `void`

Comment: _"I don't know how to work with size_types."_ It's simply a typedef that's a member of the container, so just substitute `int` with `std::string::size_type`, as I said. (You can pretty safely use `std::size_t` from `<cstddef>`, as that should cover all containers; in most cases their `size_type` will be a typedef to `std::size_t`. However, I prefer to write - and read! - the specific type for the container in question. Of course, in different cases, you can just use `auto` to avoid specifying it.)